# How to fade in Stack Navigator contained within Navigation Container?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create a smoother transition inside my Navigation Container when my app state changes. Inside the container there is a series of Stack Navigators. When the state updates to display another Stack Navigator it is essentially just an instant change with no fade/transition.

Is it possible to apply a transition to my nested Stack Navigators so that they appear smoothly?

```
        <NavigationContainer>
          {isUserLoggedIn === "initializing" && <Initializing />}
          {isUserLoggedIn === "loggedIn" && signUpFinished === "complete" && (
            <AppNavigator updateAuthState={updateAuthState} />
          )}
          {isUserLoggedIn === "loggedOut" && (
            <AuthenticationNavigator updateAuthState={updateAuthState} />
          )}
          {isUserLoggedIn === "loggedIn" && signUpFinished === "incomplete" && (
            <AboutNavigator
              updateAuthState={updateAuthState}
              updateSignUp={updateSignUp}
            />
          )}
        </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a single stack navigator and conditionally render screens instead of using separate navigators.

Then you can customize the animations with animation related options of the stack navigator.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/